# How to display article alphabetically in expression engine?

Tags: ee2

we want to sort article entries by alphabetically in expressionengine so please guide me how to display entries by alphabetically.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to sort the entries, not to filter them by their initials, use [`orderby="title"`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) and [`sort`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#sort) parameter:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
    [...}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Low Alphabet](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet/docs) for it.